# JMeter: How to replay a file upload and download jmeter testcase

Tags: php, web-applications, file-upload, download, jmeter

I am trying to test a web application having upload and download of files as a feature.

I am able to record a upload and download scenario successfully.

But I am not able to replay the test case and look up for a file literally getting uploaded (from a location specified my me) and getting downloaded to a location on my HDD.

Can anyone please help with this. I have read all the earlier posts on upload scenario, but this question pertains to replaying a (working) test case and see files getting uploaded and downloaded from/to a system.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Swapna

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use following:

1. HTTP Request Sampler with [Save Responses to a File](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) Listener - to save file
2. HTTP Request Sampler with "Use multipart/form-data for HTTP POST" checkbox enabled - to upload a file
3. *Optionally* [BeanShell Sampler](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) or [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) to create files for upload or delete files which are not required any more.
4. [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) - to perform operations above for required number of iterations